# Ruby on Rails: Is using the sleep command bad? Multithreading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading, web-applications, amazon-ec2

I am new to web development and multithreaded and I have a question on some of the concepts.

In my rails app, clients are able to submit "jobs" through a form. Each time a job is created it is passed to a module called "Dispatcher", and the dispatcher module must wait for 3 minutes before performing additional task.

In order to do this, I proposed to just run sleep for 3 minutes.

My partner said that this is a bad idea because it would freeze up the app for 3 minutes everytime a job is created.

My problem is that I dont see how this is possible. Whenever a client connects to our app (hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk), I assume that the EC2 server spins up a new thread to handle the clients request. Whenever a client creates a job, it would cause HIS thread running the app to sleep for 3 minutes. Which shouldn't be a problem because we want our app to do nothing until the 3 minutes are over.

Can someone please tell me if my concepts are correct. I want to fully understand how this works from the client making the request, to the server processing it, to sending back the HTML and javascript back to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ec2. EC2, for the most part, isn't any different than a regular server environment.

Keeping a request open for 3 minute is bad. In many scenarios you have a front end web server handing off a request to a cgi process. Which in this case is ruby. If there is no response within 30-60 seconds, the web server will often close the connection. You can often increase the timeout, but then you might run into limits with the number of open connections.

The best solution for this senario is to send a delayed message into a queue which will be processed 3 minutes later.

Comment: I know that EC2 runs just like a regular server. But, is that not how regular servers work? Everytime a client tries to access our app through the webserver, doesnt the webserver create a new thread to handle the clients request?

Comment: There are different threading models depending on your webserver, but that is essentially what happens. However, your application is not running within the web server service itself, its running in a separate process and requests are handed off from the web server via fcgi protocol. Your application process would also have to create a thread to handle the open connection. Open threads that are not doing anything use up memory, you will need to set your thread limits higher to compensate for all the threads you have waiting. You can do what you want to do, but you may run into odd issues.